# No xing symbol with moderncv class

Tags: moderncv

Unfortunately I don't get any symbols for `Xing` (and `Gitlab`) in my document footer.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


%
this part is no longer necessary or? <=======================================================
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\socialurl}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}} {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{xing}}    {\collectionadd[xing]{socials}    {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.xing.com/profile/#3}}}{}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}     {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}      {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{gitlab}}  {\collectionadd[gitlab]{socials}  {\protect\httpslink[#3]{www.gitlab.com/#3}}}      {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{skype}}   {\collectionadd[skype]{socials}   {#3}}                                            {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httpslink[#3]{#2}}}}
\makeatother
 % <========================================================



% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\social[linkedin]{john}
\social[xing]{john\_doe} 
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}
\social[skype]{jdoe} 
\extrainfo{additional information }
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt} 


\usepackage{fontawesome}   
    
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

alternative \small\faXing  and  \faXingSquare


\end{document}
```

[image]

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.2) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.2.26)

all packages should be uptodate

Comment: Works as intended for me (`LuLaTeX`), even though I do get a warning: `Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.` 

Which is to be expected: FontAwesome has no “slanted“ glyphs, so they are ignored.

Comment: do you also have a symbol at the bottom of the foot guide? I have once again added a red square to the image.

Comment: Yes, I do have symbols in the footer as well. https://i.ibb.co/dJT38kQ/cv.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your given line

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.2) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.2.26)
```

shows that you are compiling with `pdflatex`. Class `moderncv`, current version 2.1.0 calls marvo symbols with the result of some missing symbols in the footer.

To get all symbols you want add in your preamble

```
\moderncvicons{awesome}
```

to advise `moderncv` to use font awesome for all needed symbols ...

Class moderncv version 2.1.0 does not need the part of code you marked in your given mwe.

With the following mwe you can compile with `pdflatex` or `lualatex` to get all symbols:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual} % body 1, foot 1
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\social[linkedin]{john}
\social[xing]{john\_doe} 
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}
\social[skype]{jdoe} 
\extrainfo{additional information }
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{69pt} % <=========================================


%\usepackage{fontawesome}   
\moderncvicons{awesome} % <=============================================
    
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

alternative \small\faXing  and  \faXingSquare


\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image: resulting pdf page, footer]